# How do I get the contents of an <iframe> containing a different site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm able to get the 'src' attribute of an  using `.src`.  But I cannot get the  contents that are located in another domain. Is this a browser security problem?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var elementTest = $("iframe:first").get(0);
    alert(elementTest.src);  // ok
    alert(elementTest.innerHTML);  // not ok
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this ***restriction*** against inspecting content and executing code within that external domain is known as the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

The property you are looking for is contentWindow.

Try this code:

```
alert(elementTest.contentWindow.document.innerHTML);
```

It is analogous to the current window object, but for the iframe.  so you can also do this:

```
alert(elementTest.contentWindow.location.href);
```

**Edit**: Ah - I missed the fact that you have a page from another domain in the iframe.
THis method won't work for you, because of the built-in browser restrictions for one domain (your parent window) and accessing information in another domain (your iframe).

Comment: This will only work if the content loaded in the iframe is from the same domain...  in his case, this won't work.

Comment: Permission denied to get property Window.document

Comment: look like in this case, i will able to tempt with contain in google gadget

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying (in a sense) is cross-domain communication.  This won't work in the normal way you've tried (due to the same-origin policy as noted by altCognito), but there are some solutions if you have control over the other server.  Check out this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735305.aspx