# Check if specific text exists in iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I got this iframe:

```
<iframe id="frami" src="http://192.168.178.22/file.html"></iframe>
```

which contains the text:

```
var m1_enable="1"; var m1_x="0"; var m1_y="570"; var m1_w="1920"; var m1_h="510"; var m1_sensitivity="50"; var m1_threshold="0";
```

How can I check if `m1_enable="1"` exists in the iframe?

I tried this now:

```
iframe_html = document.getElementById('frami').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
if(iframe_html.includes("var")){
    alert();
}
else{
}
```

Comment: Please share some code snippet to show what you have tried till now.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545008/how-to-obtain-entire-text-content-of-a-web-page-within-a-iframe-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

If your iframe is on the same domain it is document.getElementById('frami').contentWindow['m1_enable'] (if this isn't null, compare with 1 with ==1).
otherwise, look at window.postMessage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Can you clarify, are you actually looking for text in the body of the document? It looks like you are trying to check the value if a javascript variable.

Comment: The iframe i include is the return of a cgi response. I want to change the color of a button if m1_enable=1 to green and if not to red.

Comment: I would try  var btnColour =document.getElementById('frami').contentWindow['m1_enable'] ; if(btnColour !=null && btnColour == 1) {//set to green}else{//set to red}  - sorry about the formatting, typing in phone. Using ==1 will return true if it is either a string or an integer.

Answer (score 1):

iframe tag has a property called `contentDocument that returns the document object generated by an iframe` and another called `contentWindow that returns the window object generated by an iframe`. You can check if "m1_enable="1" by

```
var x = document.getElementById("frami");
  var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
  if (y.document) y = y.document;
  if (y.body.textContent.indexOf('m1_enable="1"')>-1){
    alert('found the phrase'
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I correct the alert with ')' but it still dont alert me

Comment: what do you get when you console.log y.body.textContent

Comment: check your variable names and Id's, Share the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can get the HTML from iframe with:

```
iframe_html = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

And check if it includes `m1_enable="1"` with:

```
iframe_html.includes("m1_enable='1'")
```

This will work only if the frame source is on the same domain. If it is from a different domain, cross-site-scripting (XSS) protection will kick in.

Comment: I use now:
`iframe_html = document.getElementById('frami').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
if(iframe_html.includes("m1_enable='1'")){
    alert();
}`

but I dont get an alert... I'm on the same domain though

Comment: What does `console.log(iframe_html)` prints to console?

Comment: It logs "undefined"
Could it be a problem, that the iframe source uses <body cz-shortcut-listen="true"> as body tag?

Comment: Did you changed the iframe id to `frami` in `document.getElementById('iframe')`?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm wondering, that NONE solution is working...

Comment: Is the iframe in HTML or is loaded with JavaScript? Maybe when you trying to access the iframe is not rendered yet.

Comment: It is loaded before the javascript-script which is embedded with "<script> with the <iframe> tag

Comment: Can you share the full JS code? The solution I gave is working on my side and if the iframe is loaded via JS it's probably related with synchronism.

Comment: This is the whole code i use 
`<iframe id="frami" src="http://192.168.178.22/file.html"></iframe>
<script>
var iframe_html = document.getElementById('frami').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML; 
if(iframe_html.includes("m1_enable='1'")){     
    alert(); 
}
</script>`

Comment: [This is working](https://jsfiddle.net/ax0hf4s1/). You said above that the iframe is the return of a cgi response, what does that mean?